# Проблемы с модулем zlib

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, ssr, zlib

Пытаюсь перевести свой Лэндинг, который сделан на React'e на SSR при помощи Next.js для более лучшей поисковой оптимизации.

Выдает ошибку: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'C:\Users\rusla\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sites\jintropin-website-Jintropin-master-2-master-master\node_modules\zlib\lib'**

При этом в папке node_modules у меня есть zlib и zlib-browserify, показал на скринах.

Видел много запросов в гугле по этому поводу, но они мне не помогли. Если что то версия webpack: 5.88.2 и zlib 1.0.5.

Вот это написал в webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {


  fallback: {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "zlib": false
  },
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]